# Data Source: Address ranges for every block in NYC

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, data, address

I'm looking for data that defines the address ranges used on NYC blocks. On this screenshoot you can see google has noted the first addresses on each block of West End Avenue and 92nd/93rd/94th st.  (658, 680 and 700 respectively).  Based on that info I can extrapolate assuming that there's an even/odd side of the street and there's no unrepresented addresses to get something like this (inefficient representation used only as an example):

```
Street | btwn1 | btwn2 | first | last | side     
-------------------------------------------------
 W End | w 92  | w 93  |  658  | 678  | west/even
 W End | w 92  | w 93  |  659  | 679  | east/odd
 W End | w 93  | w 94  |  680  | 698  | west/even
 W End | w 93  | w 94  |  681  | 699  | east/odd
```

Can anyone suggest a source of this type of data? Basically it's a poor mans geocode so I can convert an address (Jeryl Metz Books - 697 West End Ave) into a suggestion of how to get there (West End btwn 93/94) even without an internet connection.  I'm sure this data is contained within OpenStreetMap, but I don't have a clue as to how one might extract/generate what I need.

[image: West End btwn 92nd and 94th st].

Comment: In general, address data does not exist in OSM in large quantities, especially in the US, so I would be very surprised if this data exists in OSM in a way that would apply to a significant portion of New York.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only publicly available source of *actual* addresses per street segment is the PAD file -- the Property Address Directory -- from the New York City Dept of City Planning.  If you rely on centerline files such as TIGER or LION, these will provide hypothetical address ranges.  The centerline data may be ok(and often is), but if you need to know the valid addresses rather than a broad range, PAD is the way to go.  The Planning Dept provides it as a free download at http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/applbyte.shtml#pad  You'll likely need to do some file manipulation, but it's a powerful data set.  Also, I believe it's updated at least annually, if not more frequently.  And it contains other useful information, such as a crosswalk between parcel IDs, addresses, and building identification numbers.

Comment: Given the OP's comments you are probably right and he would be better off with actual parcel data. At least I can't think of any reason off-hand why he would prefer the street centerline to the parcel.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of links for downloadable GIS data directly from NYC.

Street centerline data in shapefile format:

http://www.nyc.gov/html/doitt/html/eservices/eservices_gis_downloads.shtml

Streetcenterline data in MapInfo and ESRI FGDB format:

http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwnlion.shtml

From the http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwnlion.shtml website:

"A single line street base map representing the city's streets and other linear geographic features such as shorelines, surface rail lines and boardwalks, along with feature names and address ranges for each addressable street segment.

The ESRI version is released as a File Geodatabase that can only be used with ArcGIS version 9.3. In addition to the data, the geodatabase also includes two pre-built address locators that can be used out-of-the-box, with no steps to set them up. The ESRI version also comes with several layer files for viewing the data, including a Street Name Label layer and a Street Direction Arrows layer."

Answer (score 2):

http://gos2.geodata.gov/wps/portal/gos 
has NYC address ranges in .dbf format (dated 2009).

Metadata states:

The tabular data are derived from the U.S. Census Bureau's Master Address File Topologically Integrated Geographic Encoding and Referencing (MAF/TIGER) database.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would check out;

1) [NYS GIS clearinghouse](http://www.nysgis.state.ny.us/gisdata/inventories/member.cfm?organizationID=522), the [NYS ALIAS](http://www.nysgis.state.ny.us/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=932) street centerline file is actually the one you want. I've never used data from NYC so I'm not 100% sure it is available. Hence my other suggestions.

2) [Bytes of the Big Apple](http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/applbyte.shtml) Data Center (maintained by NYC Dept. of City Planning). They may have what you want (and it appears it is free according to the links [Zachary](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/data-source-address-ranges-for-every-block-in-nyc/3272#3272) pointed to).

3) [NYC Data Mine](http://www.nyc.gov/html/datamine/html/home/home.shtml). All the stuff there is free (and alot of it is the same as the info in the Bytes of the Big Apple).

4) Census TIGER line files (see Ryan D.'s [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/data-source-address-ranges-for-every-block-in-nyc/3275#3275) for a link).

Edit:

Zachary's links to NYC.gov lead to same as my BYTES of the Big Apple, I would check out the NYS GIS clearinghouse though as well. I know the ALIAS file is updated yearly (I can't say the same for the NYC.gov, although I have no reason offhand to doubt its accuracy).

Also as a note the ALIAS file has a better resolution/accuracy than the 2000 TIGER files (I would imagine the NYC.gov version does as well).

Answer (score 1):

The US Census TIGER data is available and has to/from address ranges:
http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2009/tgrshp2009.html

Download the "All Lines" shapefile for the county of your choice.  Inside you will find the attributes that you need for Left To/From (LFROMADD, LTOADD) and Right to/from (RFROMADD, RTOADD) as well as the Street Name (FULLNAME).